# echo json_encode($row) returns duplicate values

Tags: php, json

here's my php code

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from backup where owner='$email'") or die (mysql_error());
$dataCount = mysql_num_rows($result);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo json_encode($row);
```

and it returns this:

```
{"0":"1","id":"1","1":"2015","year":"2015","2":"55","necessities":"55","3":"10","savings":"10","4":"10","entertainment":"10"}
```

this is how jsonviewer.stack.hu shows it 
[image: jsonviewer]

fyi, there's only one row of data inside the table. but it seems json_encode($row) displays the value twice, but firstly using number (0 - 4) as the label, then it uses the column name (id, year, necessities, savings, entertainment) as the label.

how can I make it to display the value only once, using the column name?

Comment: What does var_dump($row) tell you about the contents of $row?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `mysql_fetch_array` to `mysql_fetch_assoc`.

`mysql_fetch_array` returns a result row  in both numeric and associative array.

`mysql_fetch_assoc` returns a result row as associative array.

Comment: awesome!! and thanks for the explanation! I'd accept your anwer in the next 10 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

You can give this functional additional arguments including `MYSQL_ASSOC`, `MYSQL_NUM`, and `MYSQL_BOTH`. In your case you want `MYSQL_ASSOC`.

However, you should be using `mysqli` and not `mysql`. the `mysql` functions are no longer maintained.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: You can also use [mysql_fetch_assoc()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) instead of giving `MYSQL_ASSOC` argument. (Same for mysqli_* functions.)

Answer (score 2):

For new versions of php ( > 5.5), use **`mysqli_fetch_assoc`** instead of `mysql_fetch_assoc`.
The `mysql_fetch_assoc` function is deprecated and is no longer maintained: Using it will lead to errors.